# fstream weird behavior

Tags: c++, serialization, fstream

I'm trying to serialize some private attributes of my class:

```
class Task {
    public:
        enum Status { COMPLETED, PENDIENT };
        // BLAH BLAH BLAH
        // CLASS GETTERS SETTERS ETC...
        const std::fstream serializeObject( std::fstream &stream );
    private:
        void setID();
        static int sCount;
        int id;
        std::string text;
        Status status;
        tm timestamp;
};
```

The serializeObject is defined like this:

```
const std::fstream Task::serializeObject( std::fstream &stream ) {
    stream.write((char *) &id, sizeof(int));
    stream.write((char *) &text, sizeof(std::string));
    stream.write((char *) &status, sizeof(Status));
    stream.write((char *) &timestamp, sizeof(tm));
    return stream;
}
```

GCC returns lot of errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:40,
                 from task.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:47: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:87: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
/usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf:770: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:78: error: within this context
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:87: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
task.cpp: In member function ‘std::fstream Task::serializeObject(std::fstream&)’:
task.cpp:104: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here
```

What am I doing wrong? Im following [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/File/SerializeobjectDemo.htm) example. Copied the store function and adapted a bit.

Comment: In addition to the obvious problem already mentioned (`std::fstream` doesn't have a copy constructor) you should probably implement your serialize method in terms of `std::ostream`: there is no need that you would try to read from it, nor do you really need and specific fjile stream operations in your implementation. Thus, taking and returning an `std::ostream&` makes your function more widely applicable.

Comment: what advantages do I get by returning the std::ostream&? Something like chaining? Would you explain me what do you mean by widely applicable? thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `Task::serializeObject()` is an `fstream`, not an `fstream&`: this is attempting to make a copy of `stream` and streams are non-copyable. From [`std::ios_base::ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/ios_base):

> The copy constuctor is deleted: streams are not copyable

Change to:

```
std::fstream& Task::serializeObject( std::fstream &stream )
```

Note I have dropped the `const` as I am unsure why this would be required.

Also, this:

```
stream.write((char *) &text, sizeof(std::string));
```

will not do what you think. A `std::string` will contain a pointer to the actual data, and the actual data will not get written to `stream` using this. Use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), possibly with [`std::string::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) so the length of the string is known when re-reading.

Comment: Thanks very much! About const, the book I read recommends using const with functions that doesn't modify the object attributes. Correct me if it is wrong :)

Comment: about writing the string to the stream, do you mean something like this: stream.write((char *) text.c_str(), sizeof(text.length()));?